# How can I script my MacBook to open Day One every morning when I open my computer?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have this idea in my mind that every morning, when I first open my computer, all programs are closed except Day One, so that I can start journaling first thing every day without any distractions.

I think it should be possible using a combination of AppleScript and Automator (and maybe a few other things), but I'm new to the Mac world, so I need a little bit of help.

Here's some pseudocode that shows what I'm thinking;

```
on wakeup, if time is between 6am and 8:30am
    quit all apps except Day One
    start Day One
end if
```

Pretty simple, but I don't know where to script it or how.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) via MacPorts and set it up to run the following AppleScript on wakeup;

```
if hours of the (current date) is greater than 6 then if hours of the (current date) is less than 9 then
    tell application "System Events"
        set theResults to get buttons of (windows of (application processes whose visible is true)) whose description is "close button" -- a list of visible applications, containing a list of windows, containing a list of (one) buttons

        repeat with anApp in theResults
            if contents of anApp is not in {} then -- windows are open
                repeat with eachWindow in (items of anApp)
                    click first item of eachWindow -- only the one minimize button
                end repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell

    tell application "Day One" to activate
end if
```

If the time is between 6am and 8am when the wakeup script is activated, it closes all open windows and launches Day One.